# Strange compilation errors in boost buffer_sequence_adapter

Tags: c++, boost

I'm writing code to connect to an instrument using a serial connection and send some commands. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <boost/asio/basic_serial_port.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


#define PORT "COM3"
#define BAUD 9600
#define DATABITS 8
#define PARITY none
#define STOP_BITS one
#define FLOW_CONTROL none

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    //Create the serial connection to the scope
    asio::io_service io;
    asio::basic_serial_port<asio::serial_port_service> scope(io);

    //Open the connection and configure it
    scope.open(PORT);
    scope.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(BAUD));
    scope.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::FLOW_CONTROL));
    scope.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::parity(asio::serial_port_base::parity::PARITY));
    scope.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::STOP_BITS));
    scope.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::character_size(DATABITS));

    //Open the connection

    //Send some test commands
    scope.write_some("MOVE X Y \n");

    //Close the port
    scope.close();

    return 0;
}
```

It looks fine in visual studio but when compiled gives me 16 errors, all in boost's buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp in its `first` section. The library code of course looks fine, so I'm not sure why it won't compile. Some of the errors are as follows:

```
Error   1   error C2825: 'Buffers': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'  c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 156 1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   2   error C2039: 'const_iterator' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 156 1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iter'    c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 156 1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   4   error C2734: 'const_iterator' : const object must be initialized if not extern  c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 156 1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   5   error C2065: 'iter' : undeclared identifier c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 156 1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   6   error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union  c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 156 1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   7   error C2825: 'Buffers': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'  c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 157 1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   8   error C2039: 'const_iterator' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp 157 1   ConsoleApplication1
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Gosh, it would help to actually see one of those 16 errors.

Comment: Woops, I'll add some to the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to wrap the literal to tell Asio how you want the buffer interpreted, e.g.

```
scope.write_some(boost::asio::buffer("MOVE X Y \n"));
```

Note, in this way the buffer includes the trailing NUL character as well. If you wanted to avoid this, you could

```
const char* message = "MOVE X Y \n";
scope.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(message, strlen(message)));
```

---

Background: the reason "it looks okay in VS" (by which you probably mean that Intellisense didn't diagnose an error before compilation) is because (at least several overloads of) `write_some` are function templates, and Intellisense doesn't actually try to  instantiate templates for the specific parameter.

Comment: I'll buy you a beer!